# Datacontext of usercontrol in TabItems inside another TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, datacontext

In my application I have a usercontrol called "ChannelControls" placed six times in six differents TabItems. The whole things is contains in an other tabcontrol. So basically, two levels of TabControls.

But since I've done that, all property stay empty and doesn't output anything. So I guess that's a datacontext problem.

Datacontext for the UserControl :

```
public partial class ChannelControls : UserControl
{
    public ChannelControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

one of its property :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VidTranslateNamesProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("VidTranslateNames", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(ChannelControls));
[Bindable(true)]
public ObservableCollection<string> VidTranslateNames
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)this.GetValue(VidTranslateNamesProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(VidTranslateNamesProperty, value); }
}
```

This is how the usercontrol is placed in one of the tabitems :

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <TabControl x:Name="MainBoard" Style="{DynamicResource BaseTabControlStyle}" TabStripPlacement="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <TabItem x:Name="Channels" Header="CHANNELS" Style="{DynamicResource BaseTabItemStyle}" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Bebas Neue Book" Margin="0" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
                       <Grid x:Name="ChannelsContent" Margin="4, 4, 4, 4" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                            <TabControl x:Name="ContentSelector" Style="{DynamicResource BaseTabControlStyle}" TabStripPlacement="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                                <TabItem x:Name="Channel0" IsSelected="True" Header="1" Style="{DynamicResource BaseTabItemStyle}" Height="45" Width="25" Background="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Bebas Neue Book">
                                    <CMiX:ChannelControls Tag="0" VidTranslateNames="{Binding VideoTranslateNames, ElementName=cmix, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                </TabItem>
                            </TabControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
               </TabControl>
           </Grid>
```

Comment: Where is the "VideoTranslateNames" property?

Comment: This one is from the usercontrol containing ChannelsControls

Comment: Run your app, go to View-> output and post the last 10 lines on your question,

Comment: I can't run it as an app, it is a usercontrol which is embeded loaded at runtime in another application.

Answer (score 0):

hmm why you have there :

> ElementName=cmix

I working with static property mainly like this:

```
        private static DependencyProperty _VidTranslateNamesProperty;

        public static event EventHandler VidTranslateNamesPropertyChanged;

        public static double VidTranslateNamesProperty
        {
            get { return _VidTranslateNamesProperty; }
            set
            {
                _VidTranslateNamesProperty = value;
                RaiseVidTranslateNamesPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public static void RaiseVidTranslateNamesPropertyChanged()
        {
            EventHandler handler = VidTranslateNamesPropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(null, new EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

then you can bind it like

```
DependencyProperty ="{Binding Path=(local:Class.VidTranslateNamesProperty)}"
```

Comment: ElementName=cmix is the usercontrol that contain ChannelsControls

Comment: anyway... In my opinion problem is raising changed event.

Comment: ok but when my usercontrol was inside only one tabitems and not like now, means a tabcontrol inside another one. I didn't have problems

Answer (score 0):

OK found the problem. Because I changed the name of the parent usercontrol, I forget to change ElementName everywhere I bind properties. As VisualStudio didn't raised any error, I needed time to find it...

Thank you anyway for the help.